# Raw Data to CSV python script

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I used cloudSim and CloudReports simulators for an experiment and i got my results into a raw data file `rawData.CRD`. Now I want to convert it to a csv file so that I can import it into RStudio for further analysis.

I followed this script.

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('rawData.CRD', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 3)
    with open('extracted.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title', 'intro', 'tagline'))
        writer.writerows(grouped)
```

It is creating a .csv file with all single row. But I want each values in seperate cells (when opened in Excel).

This is how my input raw file looks like from the simulator.

[image: input raw file]

and this is what I get after applying the script, all data as single element.

[image: output csv]

Please Help me to modify the script.

Comment: i got the script from the following thread.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248513/parse-a-plain-text-file-into-a-csv-file-using-python

Comment: As an aside, have you considered using Pandas instead of R?

Comment: No, actually I am developing an app using R. So I need this file as the input for app

Answer (score 0):

If you want the CSV file to be opened by Excel, then I suggest letting the CSV writer know that through the dialect parameter.

```
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, dialect=csv.excel)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the data presented like this,
change 3 to 1 , 
without the blank line ,just edit the "w" with "wb" 
{cr:[CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row))
I sill look for other methods to cut the group words into columns.

[image]