# txt to csv using python(replace tab with comma)

Tags: python, csv

I am asked to convert txt file of separating items by tab into the csv file of separating items by a comma,but I don't know how to use the codecs module.Here is my code:

```
import os
import csv
import codecs
filedir = input("enter the directory:")
os.chdir(filedir)
input_file = input("Enter the text file name:")
output_file = input("Enter the csv file name:")
with codecs.open(output_file, 'rU', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16248594/524743